# Umlaut and non-latin chars are getting displayed as junk in UTF-8 charset DB

Tags: c++, oracle, unix, utf-8, oracle-pro-c

I am getting non-latin content as `base64` encoded from mainframes.
I am decoding this content and inserting it into the Oracle DB which is configured for `UTF-8` charset.
But all the non latin characters are getting displayed as junk.
Even Umalut charecters are getting displayed as junk.

6 months earlier, this code was working fine. Bug appeared only recently when I was testing.
What might be the cause for this error?
Were there any updates to `Oracle` or `Unix` box which might have caused this?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you see the garbled output? It could be a setting in the client. Have you checked if old entries (back when it was 'working fine') look garbled now as well?

Comment: An "umalut charecter" sounds like one of those "southerner"-type enemies from Lord of the Rings.

Comment: How do you decode your BASE64 string? What is your `NLS_LANG` value on client side? How do you insert decoded data into Oracle? Verify your data with [DUMP](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions063.htm#SQLRF00635) function to see whether your data in DB is really wrong or "only" wrongly displayed on your client program.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting content from the mainframes, so encoding of the DB is kind of irrelevant.
What you really need to do is figure out encoding of those non-latin characters in the incoming base64 encoded data and after decoding from base64 also convert from whatever charset you have to UTF-8.
It was working fine when you tested because you provided input in same format (UTF-8) from your computer, not in the format that mainframe is giving you.

Comment: Although I am not the OP here, my coleague used my ID to post his question. Thanks for the answer.